# Javascript: Set variable to either 1 or -1

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an object that moves in a different direction when you click on it, and each time you click on it it goes faster. I have it almost functioning, but I can't get the program to exclude 0 or do only -1 or 1; I can only do a random number between -1 and 1. This means that if it hits zero, it can't progress.

(The following code is built with a Javascript engine called "Crafty". Non-javascript parts are commented as best as I can.)

```
    Crafty.init(400,320, document.getElementById('game')); // Creates canvas

    // Create variables
    var speed = 10;
    var min = -1;
    var max = 1;

    // Create a 32px by 32px red box
    var square = Crafty.e('2D, Canvas, Color, Mouse, Motion') 
        .attr({x: 50, y: 50, w: 32, h: 32}) 
        .color('red') 
    // When the red box is clicked, move it in a random direction. Make it go faster each time.
        .bind('Click', function(MouseEvent){
            speed *= 2;
            var vel = square.velocity();
            var direction = ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
            vel.x;
            vel.y;
            vel.x = (speed *= direction);
            vel.y = (speed *= direction);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this line

```
var direction = (Math.random()) > .5 ? 1 : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It really comes down to this line:

```
var direction = ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
```

If you store the acceptable values (`-1` and `1`) in an array, you can make the random choose one of those based on the length of the array. By storing the values in an array, you not only make the process simpler, but it is extensible because you can always add new values later, if desired.

```js
function getRandom(){
    var acceptable = [-1, 1];
    
    // Get a random number from 0 to 1 (the length of the array, 2, will never be reached)
    var direction = Math.floor(Math.random() * acceptable.length);
    console.log(acceptable[direction]); // Choose either array element 0 or element 1
}
  
  
// Run this code snippet a few times and you'll see that you only get -1 and 1
getRandom();
getRandom();
getRandom();
getRandom();
```

You can also remove the two lines declaring the `max` and `min` variables as they are no longer needed.